# Cómo evitar paginación en Git log?

Tags: git, docker

Estoy haciendo un script para mostrar, por cada uno de los docker que tengo levantados en mi maquina,que contienen varias aplicaciones gestionadas como clonados de git, el ultimo commit y el autor de este. De momento he hecho un bucle que me va ejecutando por cada uno de los docker, con:

```
for a in $(docker ps -aq); do
   ...
done
```

ahora la idea es ejecutar el comando de git dentro de este bucle:

```
git log -1 --pretty=format:\"%h-%an\"
```

El problema que tengo, es que este comando, aunque muestra solo la ultima linea y con el formato que yo quiero, se espera a la paginacion del comando git, por lo que hasta que no hago ctrl^C, se queda esperando en el comando, en cada uno de los docker.

he probado con:

```
git -c pager.diff=false log -1 --pretty=format:"%h-%an"
```

En teoria con desactivar pager.diff en la ejecucion, no deberia esperar a dicha paginacion (ya que es unicamente una linea, la ultima), pero sigue igual (parece que "ignore" que añado pager.diff)

Actualmente el comando que tengo (que se para por el problema de la paginacion) es este:

```
for contenedor in $(docker ps -aq); do
   $comando="git -c pager.diff=false log -1 --pretty=format:\"%h-%an\"" 

   docker exec -ti $contenedor $comando
done
```

He tenido que añadir las \ en las comillas, porque format requiere que la cadena de formato este entre comillas, y porque yo almaceno el comando en una variable, para luego ejecutarlo con docker exec.

Alguien se le ocurre algo, o quizas hay alguna otra manera de conseguir esto???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Respuesta 1**
Para evitar la paginación puedes usar el comando:

```
git --no-pager log --oneline -n 10
```

[ref](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact)

**RESPUESTA 2**

Al final usamos las herramientas según nuestras necesidades, que hagas un ***git clone*** dentro de un contenedor no tiene por que estar mal. Y que ejecutes comandos dentro de los contenedores tampoco (yo solo lo hago para tema de debug).

Ten en cuenta lo siguiente:

- Al hacer un git clone necesitas tener instalado git y todas sus dependencias. Con lo que si quieres contenedores ligeros le estas añadiendo mas tamaño.
- Piensa que las imágenes Docker como si fueran ***'artifacts'***. Con lo que deberías generar una imagen nueva con cada versión de tu repositorio. Ojo con los comandos que ejecutes en un contendor y puedan afectar al comportamiento del contenedor.

Te cuento como meto el código de mi aplicación y como accedo a la versión de git:

En mi repositorio donde tengo el código de la aplicación tengo el código de como desplegarlo en la infraestructura (Siguiendo las practicas de Infraestructura como código).
Lo mínimo que tengo junto al código de la aplicación es el Dockerfile.

Un ejemplo de Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER asg1612@gmail.com

ARG GIT_COMMIT=unspecified
ENV GIT_COMMIT=${GIT_COMMIT}
LABEL git_commit=$GIT_COMMIT

COPY src /var/local/www/src


CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Fijate en las capas ARG, ENV y LABEL

- A **[ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact)** le voy a pasar el hash del commit con el comando cuando
  hago el build, con un comando como este:

`docker build -t mi_imagen --build-arg GIT_COMMIT=$(git log -1 --format=%h) .`

- **[ENV](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env)** va a crear una variable de entorno dentro del contendor llamada GIT_COMMIT con el valor de ARG. Mi aplicación tiene acceso a esa variable, y podría devolver ese valor a una petición REST.
- **[LABEL](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#label)** va a meter esa información en el metadata de la imagen docker. Con lo que tendras acceso a esa información con el comando ***docker inspect nombre_contendor***. Tu script puede usar esta opción. (o hacer consultas api rest a tus contenedore con la opcion anterior :-P)

Comment: gracias!!! justo lo que estaba poniendo mal era lo del `--no-pager` :)

Comment: Porque respondiste dos veces? mejor editar tu respuesta si querias agregar algo. No debe responderse mas de una vez (y por eso te aparecio un cartel enorme que decia que lo evitaras)

Comment: Son dos respuestas, con aproximaciones distintas. ¿Deberían ir en la misma respuesta? ¿Una respuesta puede tener varias soluciones? Lo editaré como veas conveniente

Comment: @Jakala, por favor, ¿puedes marcar la respuesta como correcta?